# C array malloc() VS {}

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, malloc

I know that the result of

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
```

and

```
int x[100];
```

is same,but the first one is allocating heap memory,and second one is allocating stack memory.

Now i need to create a huge array(about 10000 element,not in a pattern),I think malloc() is more suitable.

But when i ready to initialize the array, I face a problem.
I cannot use any looping to init the array,how can I init an array that created by using malloc ,just like using

```
int x[100] = {1,2,3,4,......,6,7,5};
```

Comment: You can't loop-initialize your dynamic array because.... ?

Comment: *I cannot use any looping to init the array* - why not?

Comment: StackOverflow Rule of Thumb #3 is in effect: "If the OP says 'I know', they don't."

Comment: `x[0]=0; x[1]=1; x[2]=2;...` Look ma, no loops!

Comment: `int *x = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);` and `int x[100];` are not the same, and not just because of stack and heap.

Comment: Because the data is hard coded,I cannot use looping,but there is 10000 element.If I use x[0]=0,x[1]=1....,it waste the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };`, you are using an *initializer* to provide the initial data for (and infer the size of) the array `a`. This is part of the grammar of C.

When you say `int * p = malloc(1000);`, you are simply making a library call and storing a *pointer*. There is no mechanism in the language or library to provide initial values for the memory to which this pointer points, nor is it required that the pointer point to anything (it may be `NULL`).

You should notice that arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays. `a` and `p` are entirely different animals, notwithstanding the fact that you can say `p[1] = a[1];`.

Comment: Are there cases where a cannot be treated like b? This is with the exception of functions like free() and realloc(), or it being potentially unsafe to pass pointers to a.

Comment: @Paul: Sure: `int n; p = &n;` is valid, but `a = &n;` is not. Array decay produces "rvalues" (if that makes sense). Also, `&p` has type `int**`, while `&a` has type `(int*)[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot initialize the array with looping, you can use `memset()` and get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the data doesn't change, the best way is to write

```
static const int x [100] = { 23, 12, 5, 7, ... };
```

No code. No time needed for initialisation. I have actually seen code that initialised megabytes of data that way, with no problems.